# Python .pop(), How do I get it to loop infinitely by calling num.pop()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
nums = [4,3,2,1]

if len(nums) == 0:
    nums = [4,3,2,1]
```

I also tried this variation, I know in both versions boolean expression returns true.

```
nums = [4,3,2,1]

if nums == []:
    nums = [4,3,2,1]
```

Below are the results.

```
nums.pop()
1

nums.pop()
2

nums.pop()
3

nums.pop()
4

nums.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], here you don't show how you're calling `pop()` in your loop

Comment: i can't see any loop here

Comment: I am using jupyter notebooks. I want the 5th num.pop() to print out the 1 and continue the loop.

Comment: @AKR list has only 4 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want the list to be reset after it becomes empty?

```
nums = [4,3,2,1]

while True:
    while nums:
        nums.pop()
    nums = [4,3,2,1]
```

update:

```
class fake_iter:

    def __init__(self, arr: tuple):
        self.nums = arr
        self.ind = 0

    def next(self):
        res = self.nums[self.ind]
        self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % len(self.nums) # you might only need this
        return res

it = fake_iter((1, 2, 3, 4))

for i in range(10):
    print(it.next())
```

Comment: @komatiraju032 no, because you need the `nums = [4, 3, 2, 1]` to also be looped.

Comment: I believe this will run the loop infinitely, is there a way to control it so that I can use num.pop() one at a time and increment it by one and once it reaches 4, start over again from 1.

Comment: @AKR I thought you want it to be infinite to accomplish some task, if you just want cycling indices why not use range?

Comment: @VD26 Basically I want to use next() without using Yield or a massive list with repetitive values.

Answer (score 1):

May you want something like this:

```
global control, nums
control=True
nums = []
def myloop():
    global control,nums
    if control==True:
        nums = [4,3,2,1] 
        control=False

    if len(nums)==1:
        control=True

    return nums.pop()


for i in range(10):
    print(myloop())
```